# How to connect to SQL Server with windows authentication using Node js and Express js

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js, express, odbc

There is situation when you want to connect to SQL Server with Node js using Express js. Note SQL Server using **Windows Authentication**

Let says we have database: myDatase, instance: .\SQLEXPRESS, table with schema: dbo.Person

Prerequisite:
1) Node js,
2) expressjs npm packages,
3) Microsoft SQL Server,
4) ODBC Driver,
5) mssql npm packages,
6) msnodesqlv8 npm pakages.

Comment: While I can see the intend here "providing a guide" the question itself would still be considered `Too Broad` or `primarily opinion-based` IMHO - Also seeing asking questions seeking guides are off-topic I don't see how this can be different IMHO - What Questions [**Are On-Topic**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and which ones [**Are not On-Topic**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) Maybe if the answer is marked as a wiki article or what ever it is called?

Comment: Also, this question does not seem to follow the suggested pattern when choosing to answer your own question as it is not in form of a question. see [**How To Ask and Answer Your Own Question**](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) the FAQ linked when asking a question and selecting to answer it yourself.

Answer (score 4):

Here how I have done :

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   
    var sql = require('mssql/msnodesqlv8');
    var config = {
      driver: 'msnodesqlv8',
      connectionString: 'Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=myDatabase;Trusted_Connection=yes;',
    };
    const pool = new sql.ConnectionPool(config).connect().then(pool => {
        return pool.request().query("Select * From dbo.Person")
        }).then(result => {
          let rows = result.recordset
          res.status(200).json(rows);
          sql.close();
        }).catch(err => {
          res.status(500).send({ message: `${err}`})
          sql.close();
        });
      
});

var server = app.listen(5000, function () {
    console.log('Server is running..');
});
```

Comment: I would delete the cors header in case people copy/paste this and leave it in.

Comment: yes deleted Alex, thanks!

Comment: @Prateek Why is this not marked as answer? Thanks!